# How to apply attributes to KDB table using column name string and table variable?

Tags: attributes, kdb

Is it possible to apply attribute of a table using column name string?

For example (does not work):

```
t: flip `ti`p!(10:00:01 19:00:02; 77.7 88.8)
update `p#"ti" from `t
```

Also, can I update attributes of a list of tables?

For example:

```
t1: flip `ti`p!(10:00:01 19:00:02; 77.7 88.8)
t2: flip `ti`p!(10:00:01 19:00:02; 77.7 88.8)
lst: (t1; t2)
/ How can I apply `p#ti on all the elements of "lst" 
/ (i.e. acting on lst[0] and lst[1])?

/ does not always work:
i:0; while[i<=1; t: lst[i]; update `p#ti from `t; lst[i]: t; i:i+1];
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: In question #1: I am looking for a solution that would work on local tables.
In question #2: The solution can only use "lst" (can not use t1, t2). Imagine, that you have 2000 tables - does it look like a good solution to list them all one by one manually?

Comment: Regarding #1 - Solution works for locals if you pass table instead of symbol representation. You can also pass the symbol to your function and then use value to get the table representation.

Regarding #2 - I've updated the answer below to add some information about variables.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is with [functional amend](http://code.kx.com/q4m3/6_Functions/#684-general-apply-with-monadic-functions):

```
q)@[`t;`ti;`p#]
`t

q)show meta t
c | t f a
--| -----
ti| v   p
p | f
```

You can create a projection and operate over each table:

```
q)@[;`ti;`p#] each `t1`t2
`t1`t2
```

The list of tables could be contained in a variable, which you can populate programmatically (in this case, I'm just creating the variable by calling tables[]):

```
tabs:tables[]
q)@[;`ti;`p#] each tabs
`t1`t2
```

Answer (score 2):

Functional update is another option:
http://code.kx.com/q4m3/9_Queries_q-sql/#9123-functional-update

I presume you're are dynamically receiving the string hence a function similar to the below allows you to provide a string as input:

```
q)f:{[tablename;column]![tablename;();0b;(enlist `$column)!enlist (#;enlist `p;`$column)]}
q)f[`t1;"ti"]
`t1
```

Similarily to user2242865's answer a projection can be formed to operate over the two tables:

```
q)f[;"ti"]each`t1`t2
```

Comment: Somehow, the method of applying parted attributes only works on global variables. For example:

    t1: flip `ti`p!(10:00:01 19:00:02; 77.7 88.8);
    ApplyPartedAttribute: { [tableSym;columnName] ![tableSym; (); 0b; (enlist `$columnName)!enlist (#;enlist `p;`$columnName)] };
    ApplyPartedAttribute[`t1; "ti"];
    meta t1

works as expected. But not

     Test: { t1: flip `ti`p!(10:00:01 19:00:02; 77.7 88.8); ApplyPartedAttribute: { [tableSym;columnName] ![tableSym; (); 0b; (enlist `$columnName)!enlist (#;enlist `p;`$columnName)] }; ApplyPartedAttribute[`t1;"ti"]; show meta t1; }

Comment: Both @user2242865 and you use names of elements to apply attribute on a list of tables, while the essence of the question is "how to do it if those are not available? i.e. only 'lst' is available"

Comment: How you construct the variable contents is up to you. My solution shows you how to use a variable.